# How to parse jsonArray correctly in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I have json array from Json object in js like :

```
let jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
let jsonArray = jsonObject.items;
```

When I'm trying to parse it as array using

```
jsonArray.map((item)=>{
  console.warn(item.name); // also I tried with for loop like jsonArray[i].name
})
```

I got error like **TypeError: Cannot read property.**

But in jsonArray I have element with key name. Also when I'm trying print as `jsonArray[0].name` it works fine!

Example of jsonArray (Json objects on jsonArray is not same):

```
[
  {
    "name":"SomeNameHere",
    "secondKey":"secondValue"
  },
  {
    "type":"typeValue",
    "secondType":"typeValue",
  },
  {
    "name":"SomeNameHere",
    "secondKey":"secondValue"
  },
  {
    "type":"typeValue",
    "secondType":"typeValue",
  }
]
```

If it important I used Mac OS Mojave, and running `react-native run-android` on my device

```
viewListArray = jsonArr.map((item) =>  {
    console.warn(item.name);
});
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` does the parsing. Everything else you are doing is not parsing. `responce ` is JSON, the return value of `JSON.parse` is a JavaScript object, not JSON. There rest of your question is really badly formatted, so I'm really not sure what you are trying to ask. Please edit your question to make it (a) readable and (b) clear.

Comment: You need to add some information about what exactly the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on each second JSON object I don't have property name "name". and I did't check it. Now I'm checking  like item.name == undefined?item.name:'';

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonArray.forEach((item) => {
    console.warn(item.name);
});
```

Array.forEach() will loop through an array.